# Overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature

Tags: typescript

I got stuck at overload function at typescript, I did look the doc everything makes sense, even tried myself... but when I implement my own function, it screwed up.

```
async function triggerValidation<Name extends keyof Data>(payload: {
    name: Extract<keyof Data, string>;
    value?: Data[Name];
    forceValidation?: boolean;
  }[]): Promise<boolean>;
async function triggerValidation<Name extends keyof Data>(payload: {
    name: Extract<keyof Data, string>;
    value?: Data[Name];
    forceValidation?: boolean;
  }): Promise<boolean> {
}
```

[image]

So I want to accept an object or array for my function, but it giving me type error.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have just one overload. If both of those are signatures you want users of the function to see, then you need to add a third signature that denotes the implementation, and should be a union of the overload signatures.

Comment: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/function-overloads-in-typescript I dont think youre using overlaods correctly  'The first two lines of the above example list the valid overloads of the reverse function. They represent the "external" signatures of the function, if you will. On the third line, we specify the generic "internal" signature, which must be compatible with all specified overloads. Here's how these overloads show up in an IDE (Visual Studio, in this case):'

Comment: any chance can give me an example? you mean I should do {} | []

Comment: @jonathanHeindl any chance to provide an example

Comment: basically overloading works by first adding two declarations (without code) and then adding one implementation that handles both cases

Comment: the example is at the bottom of the link I provided (careful though - there is a negative exmaple first)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short Answer

> so I want to accept an object or array for my function...

You can accept an array or an object without using overloads. Instead, you can use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) with a user-defined [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) like this ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeBfA3AKB6SKABThABsB7OAEwB4A5OAW2ggA9gIA7agZygDWEEBQBmsBHAB8KdDigKoXZhABcUAKIcATnADGwWkJHj4iADRRewbQEsuAcym5FUAG5wyAVwgB+dWZwANqMLAC6LoqiFNp6EABqnrbUCLYUXP5QAEYUFGQQcFy4GHh66dZQtrwAgtq6ILK0ACpSABT2YF7A6oUNAD5QvUFhAJTqHV2V-E3DKFLyihPAAHRlXNbaXgYxKMiotfW4OHC8IFx6UKJe58BpXFA2tg4OENqJZMmp6QwqUOycPH4xjEEkQbQWCjApEoNHUJHIVDooQgMgG8JhSJUUmGODGxG0FCYVQgtByeQKXBkaDwrls4naNTqpFaUIRNBGIzkrlca145OWlAcLOhiIF3AcwAAFiNIgoMH8yLxoNTuYpefzBcK2dRltFYgkkilbukZRCoCUzdoIMAvNp7qJPErijggA)):

```js
type Data = {};

type Payload<Name extends keyof Data> = {
    name: Extract<keyof Data, string>;
    value?: Data[Name];
    forceValidation?: boolean;
}

const isArray = <T>(input: any | any[]): input is T[] =>
    input.constructor === Array;

async function triggerValidation<Name extends keyof Data>(
    payload: Payload<Name> | Payload<Name>[]
): Promise<boolean> {

    if (isArray(payload)) {
        console.log(payload.length);
    } else {
        console.log(payload.forceValidation);
    }

    return false;
}
```

## About Function Overloads

Using [a function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) would provide an additional benefit if you were wanting to support only certain parameter list combinations like this:

```js
function myFunc(p1: string, p2: boolean): void;
function myFunc(p1: number, p2: Date): void;
function myFunc(p1: string | number, p2: boolean | Date): void {
    if (typeof p1 === 'string') {
        console.log(p1, p2);
    } else {
        console.log(p1, p2);
    }
}
```

Now there is an error when the parameters do not line up with the supported overload signatures.

```
myFunc('foo', false); // works
myFunc(10, new Date()); // works
myFunc('foo', new Date()); // error
myFunc(10, false); // error
```

Although it will not provide any additional value (because you only have one parameter in your function), here for completeness sake is how your original solution would work with a function overload.

```js
function triggerValidation<Name extends keyof Data>(payload: Payload<Name>): Promise<boolean>
function triggerValidation<Name extends keyof Data>(payload: Payload<Name>[]): Promise<boolean>
async function triggerValidation<Name extends keyof Data>(
    payload: Payload<Name> | Payload<Name>[]
): Promise<boolean> {
    if (isArray(payload)) {
        console.log(payload.length);
    } else {
        console.log(payload.forceValidation);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here the overload part works but does not provide any additional value, because there are no correlated parameter lists to support.

Comment: I guess overload is not going to work with my example by support array or object, instead of union is the way to go. thanks very much for your answer

Comment: An overload would work too, but it wouldn't provide any additional benefit over only using a union type.